# Why some part of the screen recording is blurry when recorded using OBS screen recorder? Windows 7 OS

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, screen-recorder

The text in between the red lines seems to be sharp while the rest is blurry:

[image]

Comment: Some screen shots would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: You might also want to include your operating system ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Done !